# Pass a list of object references to a CFFI function

Tags: python, c, list, pointers, python-cffi

I am coding on a project where I need to process many tree-like data elements, to overcome some performance issues I want to call a given processing function already written in C with the signature `int process(Node* root)` and a tree node defined as:

```
typedef struct Node {
    int value;
    struct Node ** children;
    int num_children;
} Node;
```

Thus a tree node can have an arbitrary number of child nodes. Analogously a tree node in my Python project is defined as:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value
        self.children = list()

    def add_child(self,child):
        self.children.append(child)
```

To call the C function I would like to use [CFFI](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). The problem I ran into is that I need to convert my Python tree data structure to a matching C representation. A node representation, which can be passed to the CFFI function can be created via:

```
ffi_node = ffi.new("Node *")
ffi_node.value = some_value
```

But I could not find a way to convert the list references to children to the `struct Node** children`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type `struct node **` in C is almost equivalent to `struct node *[]`, which stands for "an array of pointers to nodes".  So you want `array = ffi.new("struct node *[]", x)`.  This allocates an array of length `x`, if it is an integer; or, you can directly put in `x` a list of the cffi pointers, e.g. `array = ffi.new("struct node *[]", [child.as_cffi_pointer() for child in self.children])`.

Be careful that all cffi objects created with `ffi.new()` must be kept alive manually as long as needed.  Just storing the C pointer somewhere will not keep alive the cffi object in Python.  If you forget to keep alive the Python-side cffi object, then the C pointer will quickly point to deallocated memory.  This concerns both the `ffi.new("struct node *")` and the `ffi.new("struct node *[]", x)`.